# Linux glibc tsearch() doesn't appear to have state (so there are no next() or previous() functions)

Tags: linux, glibc

I'm using glibc features tsearch(), tfind() to build an index.  This works well, but there appears to be no concept of "current key".  This in turn means that there are no documented functions like first(), previous(), next() or last(). 
-- Does anyone know of extensions to tsearch() which provide these functions?
-- If not, does anyone have any other suggestions (API in C required)?

Comment: Refer to [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tsearch) if not done so already. Does `twalk` do what you want?

Comment: @kaylum  Thank you...and yes, I have read the documentation.  I've also read and compiled some of the available examples.  The only "built-in" comparison which does not require twalk() is "Does the new key already exist in the index?"   As it turns out, it seems that twalk() needs to walk the complete index every time any other calculation is needed  comparing something new with the existing contents of the index.  My question was about state variables (such as a pointer to the last index entry used) and functions like previous() and next() --- but without the need for twalk() every time.